# C# - Generic Inheritance and Static Members

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance, static-members

The goal was to have a static member defined in a base class that, for each subclass that inherits from the base class, the static member would have different values (in this case, a list of the enumerable properties). I know that static members are static and so they "only exist once" and therefore can't have different values in base classes.

But I did come up with a way to make it *look* like it has different values.

Given this code:

```
public class Parent<TSelfReferenceType>
{
    public static readonly List<PropertyInfo> enumerableProperties
        = GetEnumerableProperties();

    public static Type GetTheType()
    {
        return typeof(TSelfReferenceType);
    }

    public static List<PropertyInfo> GetEnumerableProperties()
    {
        return GetTheType().GetProperties()
                           .Where(property => property.PropertyType.IsEnum)
                           .ToList();
    }
}

public class ChildA : Parent<ChildA>
{
    public EnumTypeOne ActivityType { get; set; }
    public EnumTypeTwo LogLevel { get; set; }
}

public class ChildB : Parent<ChildB>
{
    public EnumTypeThree Source { get; set; }
}
```

If I instantiate an instance of ChildA and ChildB, they each have a static enumerableProperties member with different values. Awesome!

The problem is that I don't really know what's going on under the covers. I know very little about inheritance with generics. Can somebody tell me what's going on to make this work this way?

Comment: I don't really got you question. `Parent<ChildA>` is different than `Parent<ChildB>`, so they `static` properties are initialized separately.

Comment: Your comment basically answers the question. Because I didn't know how generics worked, I didn't realize that giving a type parameter to a class it winds up creating actually different classes behind the scenes. Knowing that it winds up creating different classes makes it seem obvious that each would get its own variant of static member.

Comment: Another (simple) example, no inheritance, is `static class Test<T> { public static T Field; }`. Now it is pretty obvious that `Test<DateTime>.Field` and `Test<IDictionary<string, object>>.Field` cannot be the same field. In other words, there is a "separate" static field for each "closed" constructed generic type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can understand generics as some kind of general template for *separate* types that all work the same but are different.

In your case, `ChildA` inherits from `Parent<ChildA>`, and `ChildB` inherits from `Parent<ChildB>`. The two parent types, `Parent<ChildA>` and `Parent<ChildB>`, are different though, so `ChildA` and `ChildB` do *not* have a common base type.

It is probably easier to understand, if you actually declare `Parent<ChildA>` and `Parent<ChildB>` as real separate types:

```
class Parent_ChildA { … }
class Parent_ChildB { … }

class ChildA : Parent_ChildA { … }
class ChildB : Parent_ChildB { … }
```

This is what really happens behind the scenes. So the two parent types are separate types, which also explains why they have separate static members. Two different classes wouldn’t share static members after all, even if they have the same name.

Comment: Hi poke, may I ask if ```Parent<TSelfReferenceType>``` is in turn a subclass of some other class, say, ```Grandparent```, then for this example does it equivalent to declare ```Parent<ChildA> : Grandparent``` and ```Parent<ChildB> : Grandparent```?

Comment: @J-A-S Yeah, if `Parent<T>` is a subtype of `Grandparent` then all actual types `Parent<A>`, `Parent<B>` etc. will be direct subtypes of `Grandparent`.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, may I further ask, in that case, if ```Grandparent<T>``` is itself an open generic type, would the actual type parameters ```A``` and ```B``` in ```Parent<A>``` and ```Parent<B>``` also be passed to ```Grandparent``` (so that behind the scenes it would also declare ```Grandparent<A>``` and ```Grandparent<B>```)?

Comment: @J-A-S If `Parent<T>` inherits from a generic `Grandparent<T>`, then yes, any actual type argument `A` or `B` in `Parent<>` will be passed on to the “template” for `Grandparent<T>` and will be inserted there. So for `A` and `B`, you would end up with a `Parent_A : Grandparent_A` and `Parent_B : Grandparent_B`.